# tkz* commands vs draw/path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

I am learning TikZ and am confused about two apparent completely different ways to go about things, although they seem completely compatible and intermixable:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black] (20,20) -- (100,20);
% vs
\tkzDrawSegments((20,20),(100,20))
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm quite sure the second thing is wrong (please correct to fix this). The first way seems way more powerful (you've got nodes and all), but the second way has stuff like `tkzMarkAngle` which seems painful to do the first way.

What is the difference and how would I do a "simple thing" like `tkzMarkAngle` using paths?

Comment: `\tkzDrawSegment` is not a "native" `tikz` command. It has been implemented in another package (or perhaps in the preamble of the tex document). In this case it probably comes from `tkz-euclide`. Those "external" commands not neccesarly adhere to `tikz` conventions in syntax.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if it is possible to give a precise consideration on which package is more powerful (TikZ or the tkz bundle): what is true is that they have a different syntax, but I think there are cases in which TikZ provides a simpler programming solution and others when tkz is more straightforward.

For example, the macro `\tkzMarkAngle`, is one of the latter case. You could find the code of the macro typing in the shell:

```
gedit $(kpsewhich tkz-obj-angles.tex)
```

The following document tries to replicate the same picture with both packages and with a similar programming structure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} loads tikz
\usepackage{tkzexample}
% to display picture and code
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
tkz-based solution:
\begin{center}
\begin{tkzexample}[latex=4.5cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} 
\tkzDefPoint(2,2){A}
\tkzDefPoint(-2,3){B}
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](O,A)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](O,B)
% equivalent: \tkzDrawVectors(O,A O,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill= yellow,%
 opacity=.5](A,O,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tkzexample}
\end{center}

Ti\textit{k}Z-based solution:
\begin{center}
\begin{tkzexample}[latex=4.5cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (2,2);
\coordinate (B) at (-2,3);
\draw[thick] (B)--(O) 
 node[coordinate,pos=0.7](x-b){};
\draw[thick] (A)--(O) 
 node[coordinate,pos=0.625](x-a){};
\draw[fill=yellow,opacity=.5] 
 (O)--(x-b)  arc (125:38:0.95cm) -- (O);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tkzexample}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which provides:

[image]

As you can see, the second picture is not precise as the first one, because inside the definition of `\tkzMarkAngle` there is the exact computation for that. Not that you couldn't do the calculus with pure TikZ, but you need to complicate the code.

Answer (score 4):

`tkz`is a collection of packages based on `tikz`. These packages are compatible with `tikz`but the syntax is different. I created these packages especially for math teachers who do not necessarily want to master such a comprehensive program that `Tikz`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black] (20,20) -- (100,20);
% vs
\tkzDrawSegments((20,20),(100,20))
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Your example is not fine because if the syntax is correct for `tkz`, I think it's preferable to avoid the coordinates and it's fine to use points 
         \tkzDrawSegments(A,B)

A good code with `tkz`is composed of several parts :

1. Definition of points
2. Transformations, calculations to get segments lines circles
3. Drawing the objects
4. Drawing the marks
5. Writing the labels

`tkz` is very specific and can't replace the excellent `tikz`

Answer (score 0):

Another way without computation could be :

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkzexample}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
% to display picture and code
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
Ti\textit{k}Z-based solution:
\begin{center}
\begin{tkzexample}[latex=4.5cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (2,2);
\coordinate (B) at (-2,3);
\draw pic[%
    draw,
    fill=yellow,
    opacity=.5,
    angle radius=1cm
    ] {angle=A--O--B} ;
\draw[thick] (B)--(O)--(A) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tkzexample}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```